# onMessageSent not called in Sinch Android

Tags: android, sinch

I have an iOS app using Sinch which works without a problem, and recently I migrated the app on Android using the very same Sinch credentials(API key and API secret) then I found

```
12-14 21:57:17.678  17907-17907/com.packagename.android D/SinchClient﹕ onStarted()
12-14 21:57:17.678  17907-17907/com.packagename.android D/SinchClient﹕ mUserAgent.startBroadcastListener()
12-14 21:57:17.678  17907-17907/com.packagename.android D/SinchService﹕ SinchClient started
12-14 21:57:17.738  17907-17907/com.packagename.android I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4247f4c8 time:23957901
12-14 21:57:21.458  17907-17913/com.packagename.android I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
12-14 21:57:21.458  17907-17913/com.packagename.android I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
12-14 21:57:21.458  17907-17913/com.packagename.android I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 13
12-14 21:57:21.458  17907-17913/com.packagename.android I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
12-14 21:57:21.608  17907-18645/com.packagename.android E/sinch-android-rtc﹕ WARNING: mxp Ignoring message, reason: 'From local instance'
12-14 21:57:21.608  17907-17907/com.packagename.android W/mxp﹕ Ignoring message, reason: 'From local instance'
```

As seen above, the Sinch client has been started successfully. But `onMessageSent` is not called, why?

## My questions:

- Then why it gave me an error while I was trying to send a message?
- What does the error: "Ignoring message, reason: 'From local instance'" mean?
- `SinchService` is running and it is not null, why `onMessageSent` is not called?

## Related Code

SinchService.class

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "xxx";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "xxx";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "clientapi.sinch.com";

    private static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final SinchServiceInterface mServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();

    private SinchClient mSinchClient = null;
    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            SinchService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void receiveMessage(String payload) {
            SinchService.this.receiveMessage(payload);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            SinchService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            SinchService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mServiceInterface;
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (isStarted()) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().send(message);
        }
    }

    public void receiveMessage(String payload) {
        if (isStarted()) {
            NotificationResult result = mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
            if (result.isMessage()) {
                String msgId = result.getMessageResult().getMessageId();
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Received msg Id %s", msgId));
            }
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    private void start(String userName) {
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
                    .context(getApplicationContext())
                    .userId(userName)
                    .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                    .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

            mSinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
            mSinchClient.setSupportPushNotifications(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.checkManifest();
            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                                      ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }
}
```

SinchManager.class

```
public class SinchManager implements MessageClientListener, ServiceConnection {

    private SinchCallback callback;
    private static final String TAG = SinchManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private SinchService.SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface;
    private String chatRecipient;

    public SinchManager(Context c, SinchCallback cb) {
        this.context = c;
        this.callback = cb;
        // init Sinch
        context.getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(context, SinchService.class), this,
                context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipient, String msg) {
        mSinchServiceInterface.sendMessage(recipient, msg);
    }

    public void stopSinchClient() {
        mSinchServiceInterface.removeMessageClientListener(this);
        mSinchServiceInterface.stopClient();
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, SinchService.class));
        context.unbindService(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        if (SinchService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
            mSinchServiceInterface = (SinchService.SinchServiceInterface) iBinder;
            mSinchServiceInterface.addMessageClientListener(this);
            if (!mSinchServiceInterface.isStarted()) {
                mSinchServiceInterface.startClient(username);/// Here username="xxx"
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        if (SinchService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
            mSinchServiceInterface = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient messageClient, Message message) {
        callback.onReceiveSinchMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(MessageClient messageClient, Message message, String s) {
        callback.onSentSinchMessage(message, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient messageClient, Message message, MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
        callback.onFailedSinchMessage(failureInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient messageClient, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {
        callback.onDeliveredSinchMessage(deliveryInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient messageClient, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        //TODO setup offline push notification
        Log.d(TAG, "Recipient not online. And it's not in public chat \n Should notify recipient using push");

    }
}
```

On my activity class, I send the message like this:

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String textBody = messageTextBox.getText().toString();
    if (chatRecipient.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Recipient is empty, Check Activity Bundle");
        return;
    }
    if (textBody.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No text message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    sinchManager.sendMessage(chatRecipient, textBody);
    messageTextBox.setText("");

}
```

## Sinch Sample Code

I just tried the sample code Sinch provided and it also shows me the same error code:

```
12-16 22:48:37.713    7648-8096/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging E/sinch-android-rtc﹕ WARNING: mxp Ignoring message, reason: 'From local instance'
12-16 22:48:37.713    7648-7648/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging W/mxp﹕ Ignoring message, reason: 'From local instance'
12-16 22:48:37.863    7648-7648/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging D/MessageClient﹕ onSentMessage: NativeMessage [id=xxxxx, nativeAddress=xxxx] to recipient with idxxx
```

However I noticed that the last line of log indicates that the Message was successfully sent.

I am confused right now, is there anyone who has experience on this?

NOTE: the sample code use the same API KEY/SECRET/Environment as the one I showed above.

[Download Sinch Sample Code](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/)

Comment: I encountered the same thing. The thing is when i run the messaging sample on two android devices - it works fine, although both of the have that confusing error/warning. Hope some Sinch Dev will elaborate a bit more about this issue.

Comment: @alexk I ran this code on a real device and try to send message to an iPhone which is running sinch with a valid ID.  To make me confuse is the sinch sample can send but mine cannot

Comment: did u try to run the sinch sample with your api and send a message to a valid ID ?

Comment: @alexk yes,  that was what I did

Comment: Today i ran the sample again on two devices, both of the report that error but one of them didn't deliver any messages. Then i found out i was on airplane mode. when i disabled airplane mode it still wouldn't deliver the messages. only signing again (aka registering the user) the communication worked perfectly, although that stupid warning still appeared. hope it helps you with something. Didn't find any status report from Sinch SDK about successful registration though ...

Comment: @alexk thanks for your help.  Interesting thing is, when I try to send message from the sample app to a valid id (let's say A),  it can be sent (got the message sent call back),  if I try to send a message from my app, using the very same sinch credentials to the same recipient A,  the message sent call back is not called. My app using the same sinch service implemented by the sample app,  so that makes me very confused.  Thanks for your info though,  I'll continue to investigate this.

Comment: @ss1271 did you get the sample messaging app included in the SDK working?

Comment: @mravca yes I did. And I also solved my problem, I'll update the question later

Comment: @ss1271 Great to hear!

Comment: @ss1271 Could you update this question with an answer?

Comment: @mravca Hi, sorry to get back late. This question is actually obsolete, please refer to this one instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809882/android-parse-com-push-notification-not-sent I hope it can help

Comment: @ss1271 could you either add an answer or delete this question then please.